# How to reset router-link id in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b>Vuejs dynamic routing</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b>{{ item.id }}.</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'UserWithID', params: { id: item.id } }">
        {{ item.kk }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <User />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "./User.vue";
import { datalist } from "./datalist";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    User,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: datalist,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**datalist.vue**

```html
export const datalist = [
  { id: 1, val: "11", kk: "potter" },
  { id: 2, val: "22", kk: "james" },
  { id: 3, val: "55", kk: "limda" },
  { id: 4, val: "77", kk: "stepen" }
];
```

**main.js**

```html
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex"
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const store = new Vuex.Store(
  {
    plugins: [createPersistedState({

      storage: window.sessionStorage,
    })],
    state: {

    },
    mutations: {
      // setAuthentication(state, status) {
      //   state.authenticated = status;
      // }
    }
  }
);
```

I want to reset the `router-link` id. the issue is like, When I click on router-link, in the URL section, I can see pathname/component name followed by id.

When I click on the back button every time I can see my action like:

```
/1../2 .../3
```

In the URL section. I want to reset the value when clicking on the back button. and on page refresh array from v-for is getting cleared.

Working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-cherry-p5s9b?file=/src/main.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you did not use history mode for the router, I highly recommend this mode because it resets the router, you cannot do anything about it in the helloworld vue, you have to go to your router file and add/change this code:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
```

I hope this will work for you, this will also remove the `#` in your route.

If this still does not work, you can try creating a new vue project with the router set to history mode.

Comment: No it did not work.  I have created codesandbox with some example here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-dhawan-3id77?file=/src/components/User.vue

Comment: As you can see when i clicked on router-link, Based on the id. I am redirected to the user.vue component. and there i modified some info and clicked on submit again. Details are updated but after page refresh entire array is getting reset.

Comment: Did you try to recreate the project with history mode?